# ORA-00922: missing or invalid option, when inserting values to table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (
Customer_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
Customer_Name VARCHAR(25),
Customer_Age INT,
Customer_City VARCHAR(20)
);
INSERT into CUSTOMER values (1, 'Simon Li', 21, 'New York');
INSERT into CUSTOMER values (2, 'Richard Andrew', 34, 'San Diego');
INSERT into CUSTOMER values (3, 'Catherine Wong', 27, 'Tucson');
INSERT into CUSTOMER values (4, 'Marie', 28, 'Tucson');
INSERT into CUSTOMER values (5, 'Bob Richard', 27, 'San Diego');
```

Creating the table runs fine. But when adding insert into it gave me error. That's the code, why won't it work??

Edit:
I have changed the code to

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER(
Customer_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
Customer_Name VARCHAR2(25),
Customer_Age INT,
Customer_City VARCHAR2(20)
);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (1, 'Simon Li', 21, 'New York');
```

changed the extra 'S' and changed to VARCHAR2. but unfortunately still doesn't work..

Comment: Should it not be `INSERT into CUSTOMER (Customer_ID, Customer_Name, Customer_Age, Customer_City)  values (1, 'Simon Li', 21, 'New York');`

Comment: I think the issue is your table name is CUSTOMERS with a S and you are using only CUSTOMER in Insert statement.

Comment: Apart from misspelled table name (as Ankit said), and the fact that you'd rather use VARCHAR**2** datatype, the rest is OK. Which tool do you use to run INSERT statements, and how exactly do you do that?

Comment: I did all of the things above but still the same error, I updated my code above

Comment: You have a  primary key error -- you already have a value of `1` in the table.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented: everything is OK with your code (when typos are fixed):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (
  2  Customer_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  3  Customer_Name VARCHAR2(25),
  4  Customer_Age INT,
  5  Customer_City VARCHAR2(20)
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT into CUSTOMERS values (1, 'Simon Li', 21, 'New York');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT into CUSTOMERS values (2, 'Richard Andrew', 34, 'San Diego');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT into CUSTOMERS values (3, 'Catherine Wong', 27, 'Tucson');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT into CUSTOMERS values (4, 'Marie', 28, 'Tucson');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT into CUSTOMERS values (5, 'Bob Richard', 27, 'San Diego');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

There's no evidence of ORA-00922, so - either this isn't all you executed, or you executed it in an inappropriate way, used a tool which doesn't "understand" what you are doing ... who knows? But, as of this particular code, it is OK as far as ORA-00922 is concerned.

Comment: Thanks! My mistake was I already created an identical table beforehand. Therefore the query was denied.

Comment: But, in that case, Oracle would report **ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object**, not ORA-00922.